# Swift HTTP Stub doesn't work. (Alamofire 3.0 & Mockingjay)

Tags: swift, alamofire, stub

HTTP Stub doesn't work. (Alamofire 3.0)

I want to stubbing http request with Alamofire(3.0) and Mockingjay.

I tried stub with OHHTTPStubs.

but it doen't work too..

here is my test code.

What should I do?

#### Versions

Alamofire 3.0

Mockingjay 1.1.1

Xcode 7.3 beta

```
import Quick
import Nimble
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import Mockingjay

@testable import testApp

class apitestSpec: QuickSpec {

var email:String = ""

override func spec() {
    describe("API") {
        context("test get request") {
            beforeEach() {
                let body = [ "email": "test@test.com" ]
                self.stub(http(.GET, uri: "http://localhost/api/user"), builder: json(body))
            }

            it("returns json") {
                Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://localhost/api/user")
                    .responseJSON { response in
                        switch response.result {
                        case .Success(let value):
                            self.email = JSON(value)["email"].stringValue
                        case .Failure(let error):
                            print(error)
                        }
                }
                expect(self.email).toEventually(equal("test@test.com"))
            }
        }
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to work around this issue?

Comment: where is able to slove the problem

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue.

Replacing

```
self.stub(http(.GET, uri: "http://localhost/api/user"), builder: json(body))
```

with

```
MockingjayProtocol.addStub(http(.GET, uri: "http://localhost/api/user"), builder: json(body))
```

did the trick!

Hope this helps